# What language do Cantonese people use when reading Chinese?

Tags: cantonese, reading

When reading a book or a newspaper, what language do Cantonese people read in? Do they read in mandarin or Cantonese? Or do they subconsciously translate it into colloquial Cantonese since most words have a direct facsimile from mandarin? Also how do less literate people handle understanding Cantonese songs, which is sung in standard Chinese using Cantonese words? Finally, how do Cantonese schoolchildren learn in school?

Answer (score 3):

***When reading a book or a newspaper, what language do Cantonese people read in? Do they read in mandarin or Cantonese?***

In Cantonese, of course.

Cantonese and Mandarin are not mutually intelligible, mainly due to a difference in their phonology. They share the same written language but each has its own set of pronunciation of the characters.

***Or do they subconsciously translate it into colloquial Cantonese since most words have a direct facsimile from mandarin?***

Cantonese can be written verbatim, but many of the characters are not regularly used. Instead, a non-verbatim formalized written form (same as Mandarin written form) is adopted. When a Cantonese speaker reads aloud a piece of writing, s/he uses Cantonese pronunciation. You, as the listener, will be able to tell that s/he is reading from a text, and not speaking colloquially.

***Also how do less literate people handle understanding Cantonese songs, which is sung in standard Chinese using Cantonese words?***

It is actually not that difficult, since most of the content words are the same, whether spoken or written. The words that are different from the spoken form are mostly function words.

***Finally, how do Cantonese school children learn in school?***

Cantonese school children learn in Cantonese. When they learn to read and write, they learn the standard Cantonese pronunciation of the written characters.

I have included a link here if you are interested in reading more about the Cantonese language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese

You can also google "History of the Cantonese language" for more information.

Comment: I think the answers to the last two questions are objectionable.  I am a well-educated non-Cantonese-speaking Chinese, who has great difficulty understanding Cantonese conservation or singing.  Does China allow teaching using a language other than Mandarin?

Comment: @r13  Please define "objectionable" Do you mean "wrong"?

Comment: @WayneCheah Objectionable 1) Causing disapproval or protest. 2) Liable to objection or debate; used of something one might take exception to. Whichever definition you feel fits my line of writing. Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @r13 Answer to the last question is drawn from my own, and the experience of millions of Cantonese speaking school children in Hong Kong, Macau, and possibly in other places, over decades. The OP isn't asking about the school system of the PRC per se.

Comment: @r13 And the question about less literate people and Cantonese songs, well, my understanding is that the OP wants to know how Cantonese speakers who are not literate  handle song lyrics which is often is more formal, written style language. I don't think it has anything to do with non-Cantonese speakers at all.

Comment: @r13 You said, "I am a well-educated non-Cantonese-speaking Chinese, who has great difficulty understanding Cantonese conservation or singing." I think my answer touched on that. You have problems understanding Cantonese because Mandarin and Cantonese are not mutually intelligible. You aren't supposed to be able to understand without learning it.

Comment: In the answers above, you have proved why they are objectionable because there are exceptions readily available. I don't quite understand the "less literate...", as there are/were many Chinese without formal education, but I don't think they have a problem listening to contemporary music/songs and fully understand the lyrics in Chinese, which is the language they speak daily. Writing is another story though.

Comment: How does having exceptions have anything to do with being objectionable?? I don't really know what you are trying to get at. What exceptions are you talking about?

Comment: And about the "less literate" people, well, you said, and I quote: ... I don't think they have a problem listening to contemporary music/songs and fully understand the lyrics in Chinese. If semi-literate Mandarin speakers can understand Mandarin song lyrics, and (I said) semi-literate Cantonese speakers can understand Cantonese song lyrics, what is the problem here? What exactly do you not agree with?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to separate the written languages and spoken languages here. The Latin alphabet, for example, is used by many spoken European languages, yet almost nobody nowadays would say "I speak Latin" because the written language is simply a writing system with a fossilized name from its roots. The same can be said about the Chinese writing system, especially in older times. For example, 身体 means "body" in both Japanese and Chinese, yet Japanese people would only read it with their specific pronunciation ("shin tai") and Chinese people would use theirs ("shen ti").

A more complicated example is how this sentence is written in Chinese to mean "My name is Shawn.":

我叫肖恩。

And this sentence in Japanese meaning the same thing:

私はショーンです。

Both technically have Chinese characters in the sentence, but you can see the differences become more extreme. With Cantonese, you typically don't have as dramatic of differences given they don't have syllabaries like Japanese, but consider this example for "what is this?" in Mandarin:

這個是什麽? (sounds like: "zhe ge shi shen me")

And in Cantonese:

呢個係咩? (sounds like: "li go hai me")

The pronunciations *and* characters differ radically despite the sentence meaning essentially the same thing.